# Proving that concatenating two increasing lists produces an increasing list

Tags: idris

Let's consider a predicate showing that the elements in the list are in increasing order (and for simplicity let's only deal with non-empty lists):

```
mutual
  data Increasing : List a -> Type where
    SingleIncreasing  : (x : a) -> Increasing [x]
    RecIncreasing     : Ord a => (x : a) ->
                                 (rest : Increasing xs) ->
                                 (let prf = increasingIsNonEmpty rest
                                  in x <= head xs = True) ->
                                 Increasing (x :: xs)

  %name Increasing xsi, ysi, zsi

  increasingIsNonEmpty : Increasing xs -> NonEmpty xs
  increasingIsNonEmpty (SingleIncreasing y) = IsNonEmpty
  increasingIsNonEmpty (RecIncreasing x rest prf) = IsNonEmpty
```

Now let's try to write some useful lemmas with this predicate. Let's start with showing that concatenating two increasing lists produces an increasing list, given that the last element of the first list is not greater than the first element of the second list. The type of this lemma would be:

```
appendIncreasing : Ord a => {xs : List a} ->
                            (xsi : Increasing xs) ->
                            (ysi : Increasing ys) ->
                            {auto leq : let xprf = increasingIsNonEmpty xsi
                                            yprf = increasingIsNonEmpty ysi
                                        in last xs <= head ys = True} ->
                            Increasing (xs ++ ys)
```

Let's now try to implement it! A reasonable way seems to be case-splitting on `xsi`. The base case where `xsi` is a single element is trivial:

```
appendIncreasing {leq} (SingleIncreasing x) ysi = RecIncreasing x ysi leq
```

The other case is more complicated. Given

```
appendIncreasing {leq} (RecIncreasing x rest prf) ysi = ?wut
```

it seems reasonable to proceed by recursively proving this for the result of joining `rest` and `ysi` by relying on `leq` and then prepending `x` using the `prf`. At this point the `leq` is actually a proof of `last (x :: xs) <= head ys = True`, and the recursive call to `appendIncreasing` would need to have a proof of `last xs <= head ys = True`. I don't see a good way to directly prove that the former implies the latter, so let's fall back to rewriting and first write a lemma showing that the last element of a list isn't changed by prepending to the front:

```
lastIsLast : (x : a) -> (xs : List a) -> {auto ok : NonEmpty xs} -> last xs = last (x :: xs)
lastIsLast x' [x] = Refl
lastIsLast x' (x :: y :: xs) = lastIsLast x' (y :: xs)
```

Now I would expect to be able to write

```
appendIncreasing {xs = x :: xs} {leq} (RecIncreasing x rest prf) ysi =
  let rest' = appendIncreasing {leq = rewrite lastIsLast x xs in leq} rest ysi
  in ?wut
```

but I fail:

```
When checking right hand side of appendIncreasing with expected type
        Increasing ((x :: xs) ++ ys)

When checking argument leq to Sort.appendIncreasing:
        rewriting last xs to last (x :: xs) did not change type last xs <= head ys = True
```

How can I fix this?

And, perhaps, my proof design is suboptimal. Is there a way to express this predicate in a more useful manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rewrite` doesn't find the right predicate, try to be explicit with `replace`.

```
appendIncreasing {a} {xs = x :: xs} {ys} (RecIncreasing x rest prf) ysi leq = 
  let rekPrf = replace (sym $ lastIsLast x xs) leq
               {P=\T => (T <= (head ys {ok=increasingIsNonEmpty ysi})) = True} in
  let rek = appendIncreasing rest ysi rekPrf in
  let appPrf = headIsHead xs ys {q = increasingIsNonEmpty rek} in
  let extPrf = replace appPrf prf {P=\T => x <= T = True} in
  RecIncreasing x rek extPrf
```

with

```
headIsHead : (xs : List a) -> (ys : List a) ->
             {auto p : NonEmpty xs} -> {auto q : NonEmpty (xs ++ ys)} ->
             head xs = head (xs ++ ys)
headIsHead (x :: xs) ys = Refl
```

Some suggestions:

1. Use `Data.So x` instead of `x = True`, makes run-time functions
   easier to write.
2. Lift `Ord a` from the constructor to the type, making it
   more clear which ordering is used (and you don't have to match on
   `{a}` at `appendIncreasing`, I guess).
3. Don't forget that you can
   match on variables in constructors, so instead of repeating that `Increasing xs` has
   `NonEmpty xs`, just use `Increasing (x :: xs)`.

Leading to:

```
data Increasing : Ord a -> List a -> Type where
  SingleIncreasing : (x : a) -> Increasing ord [x]
  RecIncreasing    : (x : a) -> Increasing ord (y :: ys) ->
                                So (x <= y) ->
                                Increasing ord (x :: y :: ys)

appendIncreasing : {ord : Ord a} ->
                   Increasing ord (x :: xs) -> Increasing ord (y :: ys) ->
                   So (last (x :: xs) <= y) ->
                   Increasing ord ((x :: xs) ++ (y :: ys))
```

Should make proving things a lot easier, especially if you want to include empty lists.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! In the meanwhile, I guess I have figured why `rewrite` wasn't working for me, and why I got other sources of strange errors - in short, constraints for `Ord a` arising from different sources were not unified by the type checker for some reason, hence I had funny type mismatches (`:set showimplicits` really helped to debug). In addition to your suggestions, I've replaced `Ord a` with a function `a -> a -> Bool` that's supposed to be a preorder, and made `Increasing`'s type depend on it, which seems to produce even cleaner code with way less required lemmas.

Comment: I've never heard of "Make all proofs implicit arguments, so they can get erased.". AFAIK: Implicit implicit arguments (those that aren't given in braces but implicitly made implicit by being lowercase) are marked for erasure, but explicit implicit arguments (given in braces) are never erased unless asked. Same for explicit arguments. You can mark any explicitly given argument as erased, by using `.{x : tp}` or `.(x : tp)`. Complex proof arguments are usually explicit. Anyway, I don't think you *can* erase them here, because the proofs in them are used in the result.

Comment: @HTNW you are right, thanks! (But at least here Idris can erase the proofs: `--warnreach` with `.(So (x <= y))` compiles without warning. The proofs are only needed for, well, the proof parts.)